# Validator.TryValidateObject always returns true in all cases

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I've a class which has two properties. I want to validate one of them, which is another class and I've already stated the         `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Error message", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]` on every single property I want to validate.

```
public partial class Factura
{
    [JsonProperty("Cabecera")]
    public Cabecera Cabecera { get; set; }
    public string Imagen { get; set; }
}

public partial class Cabecera
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe especificarse un emisor", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [JsonProperty("Emisor")]
    public string Emisor { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe especificarse un número de factura", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [JsonProperty("Factura")]
    public string Factura { get; set; }
}
```

Actual execution of the validation:

```
var test = new Factura();
var errors = new List<ValidationResult>();
Validator.TryValidateObject(test, new ValidationContext(test), errors, true);
```

The `Validator.TryValidateObject(test, new ValidationContext(test), errors, true);` is always returning `true` when it's obvious the object shouldn't pass the validation.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was **I wasn't specifying the correct `ValidationContext`** (actually `Cabecera` class & property) since I was supposing (with no arguments) that creating a ValidationContext of the "parent" class itself would "magically" validate every single property using the `DataAnnotations`.

Just be careful about what are you trying to validate and which `ValidationContext` are you actually creating!

```
var test = new Factura();
test.Cabecera = new Cabecera();
var errors = new List<ValidationResult>();
Validator.TryValidateObject(test.Cabecera, new ValidationContext(test.Cabecera), errors, true);
```

Comment: You probably should put `[Required]` on `Factura`'s `Cabecera` property

Comment: @MickyD That worked so far! So, that explicitly forces validation on that property? Even further, because on that _tryout_ `Cabecera` would be null!